# Cmake cannot find OpenMP (Centos + homebrew)

Tags: centos

I am trying to install mxnet and xgboost from source. With both I get an error from cmake that it cannot find OpemMP, the error is the same for both libraries so I am guessing is an issue with my setup.

```
CMake Error at /home/mguzman/.linuxbrew/Cellar/cmake/3.19.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_pthread_LIBRARY) (found version
  "4.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/mguzman/.linuxbrew/Cellar/cmake/3.19.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:582 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /home/mguzman/.linuxbrew/Cellar/cmake/3.19.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:529 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:148 (find_package)
```

I have done `brew install libomp`. I tried using different versions of gcc but no luck. I tried rebuilding gcc but no luck. I tried `pip3 install cmake` but it also did not work.

I tried `export OPENMP_HOME="~/.linuxbrew/opt/libomp"` and `export OPENMP_DIR="~/.linuxbrew/opt/libomp"` but it did not work.

I tried

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/home/mguzman/.linuxbrew/opt/libomp/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/mguzman/.linuxbrew/opt/libomp/include"
```

as suggested by brew, but it also did not work. I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with my own cmake file. I fixed it by hinting cmake to the right directories

`find_library(LIBOMP OpenMP omp omp5 HINTS "~/.linuxbrew/opt/libomp/lib")`

and then later link with `target_link_libraries(MyProject INTERFACE ${LIBOMP})`.

Not sure if this is an option for you to edit the cmake file, or if this can be easily done.

However, my solution above first did not work because I set the hint to `~/.linuxbrew/opt/libomp`, like you set the shell variables. Maybe it already helps to append the `lib/` directory?